# I'm getting a "githubClientID" is not defined when calling the "config" package using the GitHub API

Tags: javascript, postman, github-api

I'm creating a feature that to retrieves GitHub user names via the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

When sending the GET request from Postman, I got a server error that reads:

> *"Configuration property "githubClientId" is not defined"*

Despite the fact that I called the `config` package with `githubClientID` defined in `config/default.json`, like this:

```
{
  "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://massas:oir@socialapp-2dg3r.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  "jwtToken" : "oecret",
  "githubClientId:": "ID",
  "githubSecret": "SECRET"
}
// change the values for public viewing
```

Here's the code that's calling the API:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const config = require('config');

// @route       GET api/profile/github/:username
// @desc        Get user repos from username
// @acess       Private
router.get('/github/:username', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const options = {
      uri: `https://api.github.com/users/${
          req.params.username
        }/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${config.get(
          'githubClientId'
        )}&client_secret=${config.get('githubSecret')}`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'user-agent': 'node.js'
      }
    };
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) console.error(error);
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          msg: 'No Github profile found'
        });
      }
      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: As obvious as this might be, please don't share your (or anyone else's) private ID(s) and/or password(s) or passphrase(s) online.

Comment: I don't understand if you are getting the error in your js code or postman or both. If both can you also post the js error?

Comment: @mb_s88 in js code I'm getting the not defined error. In postman all I get is the 'Server Error' from the res.status in the catch

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to change the options object from:

```
const options = {
  uri: `https://api.github.com/users/${
      req.params.username
    }/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${config.get(
      'githubClientId'
    )}&client_secret=${config.get('githubSecret')}`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'user-agent': 'node.js'
  }
};
```

to:

```
const uri = encodeURI(
  `https://api.github.com/users/${req.params.username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc`
);
const headers = {
  'user-agent': 'node.js',
  Authorization: `token ${config.get('githubToken')}`
};

const gitHubResponse = await axios.get(uri, { headers });
```

2- Make sure to add a default.json file in config folder with your GitHub secret access token

`{ "githubToken": "<yoursecrectaccesstoken>" }`

3- Install axios in the root of the project, if you didn't install it

`npm i axios`

Comment: I tried this, and now I am getting 
" Request failed with status code 401 "